# How to cache go dependencies for subsequent, distinct docker builds

Tags: docker, go, aws-codebuild

In a AWS Codebuild project I am building docker containers for multiple services one after the other. They all use a centralized `go.mod`, `go.sum`, and `vendors/modules.txt` file, though in each Dockerfile, I'm not calling `go mod tidy; go mod vendor`, I'm just copying the necessary directories from the Codebuild source and running `go build service_a`.

There are shared libraries between service_a and service_b, which is not cached after the service_a docker build. There is a technique to cache dependencies for subsequent builds of the same docker container: https://docs.docker.com/build/cache/#use-the-dedicated-run-cache, but is there a way to cache dependencies in between different image builds?

File structure:

DockerfileA:

```
COPY go.mod /root/app
COPY go.sum /root/app

COPY service_a /root/app

WORKDIR /root/app/service_a
RUN go build service_a
```

DockerfileB:

```
COPY go.mod /root/app
COPY go.sum /root/app

COPY service_a /root/app

WORKDIR /root/app/service_b
RUN go build service_b
```

buildspec.yaml

```
docker build -t service_a -f service_a/Dockerfile .
docker build -t service_b -f service_b/Dockerfile .
```